# What hash function is used for web search engine indexing

Tags: search, data-structures, indexing, web, hashtable

I assume that this question may be slightly too open ended, but I am curious to know how does hashing works when web search engines index web pages. What are the some of the common hash codes being used for that purpose?

Comment: I have no expertise in this matter but I was wondering why you even need a hash function, why not use the words (or phrases) themselves? To me it looks like hashing is an extra layer, which serves no function.

Comment: what I am trying to understand is how web search engines index their pages. Since they are using hashtables to store all the pages, there should be some hash function involved. Does it make sense?

Comment: A good question TommyG +1. Each word or string can be converted to an integer as that would make the comparision super quick. Remember that even a ph rase would yield some unique int value after hashing (forget collisions for a moment) so for finding/searching that phrase/word would be quick O(1) if it is an int as opposed to string matching.

Comment: I would think that murmurhash3 would be a good fit, for it's speed and collision properties.  http://code.google.com/p/smhasher/wiki/MurmurHash3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Sphinx Search Engine which is an extremely popular open source product and comparable to Lucene, the hash function used is CRC. It converts each word found in douments which it is indexing to a 32 bit/64 bit int using CRC.

Comment: Sphinx rocks. Nice to see it getting some love!